# Slider.IsMoveToPointEnabled in Avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

What's the equivalent of [Slider.IsMoveToPointEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.slider.ismovetopointenabled?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in Avalonia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that MoveToPoint is the default behavior in Avalonia.